# Install PECL Memcached Error

Tags: php, memcached, pecl, libmemcached

I followed the following steps to install PECL memcached in my Centos Server, always got errors.

First. Install libmemcached

```
cd /opt
wget http://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/0.40a/+download/libmemcached-0.40.tar.gz
tar -xzvf libmemcached-0.40.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-0.40
./configure
make
make install
```

Secondly, Install PECL memcached

```
cd /opt
pecl download memcached-1.0.2
tar zxvf memcached-1.0.2.tgz
cd memcached-1.0.2
phpize
./configure --with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/libmemcached-0.40/libmemcached
```

I always got error

```
checking for memcached igbinary support... disabled
configure: error: Can't find libmemcached headers under "/opt/libmemcached-0.40/libmemcached"
```

Actually `memcached.h` file is in `/opt/libmemcached-0.40/libmemcached` direcotry.

Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried without --with-libmemcache-dir

Comment: Yes, I tried but got `ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no' failed
`

Comment: I also got `error 'configure: error: no, sasl.h is not available. Run configure with --disable-memcached-sasl to disable this check
'` when tried without `--with-libmemcache-dir`

Answer (score 11):

To solve this issue with CentOS, you should be able to run:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
```

FYI, this question refers to CentOS, but for Ubuntu, the following should work:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use configure with that option:
`./configure --disable-memcached-sasl`

and it won't need to check for the sasl libs.
I did and could then compile...

Not sure why when you specific the --with-libmemcache-dir, it can't figure out where sasl.h is inside that directory... Anyway Here is someinfo on how to setup SASL for memcache... just not sure how to actually get sasl.h recognized within the ./configure script
https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto
Note: Im not too familiar with SASL but you might want SASL if you are on some sort of shared hosting environment.