# error when installing pecl memcached

Tags: centos, memcached, pecl

I've been having real trouble installing the pecl memcached package.

Have not had any joy with any yum or pear/pecl install commands I referred to this question [Install PECL Memcached Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102326/install-pecl-memcached-error) and started trying to configure/make manually

I'm using pecl to download the latest (memcached-2.2.0) then untar, phpize...

If I configure with --disable-memcached-sasl the configure completes but make fails. With what looks like syntax errors

```
In file included from /root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached_private.h:28,
                 from /root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c:26:
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_libmemcached_compat.h:56: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’     or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘php_memcached_instance_st’
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c:328: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘php_memcached_instance_st’
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c:329: error: expected declaration specifiers or     ‘...’ before ‘php_memcached_instance_st’
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c:330: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘php_memcached_instance_st’
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c: In function ‘php_memc_get_impl’:
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c:594: warning: passing argument 4 of     ‘memcached_mget_by_key’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/libmemcached/memcached_get.h:38: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’
/root/memcached-2.2.0/php_memcached.c: In function ‘php_memc_getMulti_impl’:
```

There's more of that but hopefully thats a useful enough indicator

If I use --with-libmemcached-dir=/usr/include/libmemcached i get

```
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: Unable to find memcached.h under /usr/include/libmemcached
```

But that IS where memcached.h is

If I use --with-libmemcached-dir=no configure gives

```
configure: error: no, libmemcached sasl support is not enabled. Run configure with --disable-memcached-sasl to disable this check
```

If i add the --disable-memcached-sasl option, it configure completes but make fails with the syntax errors again

Feel like I'm stuck in a loop.

This isn't the first time I've set up a server from scratch to use memcached (although first time in a while I guess) I don't remember having any issues before.

Any ideas please anyone?

**This looked like a good lead**

http://blusmurf.net/2012/08/27/pecl-memcache-build-error/

But not joy still

**I've also been investigating this issue from php-memcached's github page**

https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/69

I've tried with 2.1 and 2.2 now, hacking the files to try and get make to build. Still no luck...

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem with  libmemcached & memcached.h. I am digging into it & will update if I figure it out. Please update if you find a solution.

Comment: I tried to install 1.0.16 of libmemcached to use with php-memcached-2.1 but had errors building libmemcached ;-)

I'm still googling and fiddling, ill let you know. Or I'll use redis :-D

Comment: Although I have installed Memcached successfully ( what errors are you getting when building libmemcached ? ), even I am going for Redis - as in my use case, I want to cache objects, Session storage which will be sharing between different applications. Memcached cannot be used for Session storage ( not atleast without a twisted approach ), hence redis it is \m/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved it by using this combination:

1. libmemcached [release 1.0.16](https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.16) - installed from source
2. php-memcached [release 2.1.0](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/releases/tag/r2.1.0) - installed from source & Added memcached.so in php.in

I Hope this help.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I'll take your word for it in case someone finds this as everything I've read suggests it's correct. It was just my specific issue building libmemcached prevented me from testing

Comment: Yes, it works. If it does not work for YOU check if you don't have libmemcached 1.1.16+ installed instead of libmemcached 1.0.16+.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't need SASL, answer with this:

libmemcached directory [no] : no --disable-memcached-sasl

Comment: this did the trick, without going through any loopholes or having to download and compile specific packages or versions from source

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1** - Install SASL:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
```

**Step 2** - Compile libmemcached with SASL installed:

```
cd ~
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-1.0.18
./configure
make && make install
```

**Step 3** - Install PHP Memcached:

```
pecl install memcached
```

(Do not specify `libmemcached-dir`)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont need sasl support here is an easy way to install 2.2.X:

```
pecl_memcached_ver="2.2.0"
pecl download memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}
tar xzvf memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}.tgz
cd memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}/
phpize
./configure --disable-memcached-sasl
make
make install
cd ..
rm -r memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}
echo "extension=memcached.so" > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-memcached.ini
```

Then run `php5 -i` to test that it installed 2.2.x correctly

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. sudo apt-get install libmemcached libmemcached-dev
2. sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/libmemcached && sudo ln -s /usr/include/libmemcached/memcached.h /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/libmemcached/memcached.h
3. echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-memcached-sasl" | sudo /opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.4.40/bin/pecl -C /opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.4.40/etc/pear.conf install memcached

Setup:
Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS x64 (trusty tahr)
phpfarm (latest) with pecl
PHP 5.4.40
memcached 2.2.0

NOTE: Obviously, you must replace the paths according to your system

Answer (score 0):

The procedure @rynop is very good and its all great!

Now how about you want to package for deployment? My target deployment runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want it to replace upstream `php5-memcached` package as a simple *.deb* file.

For this, take a [look at fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) which stands for "*Freaking Package Manager*" (sic). Its made to create packages out of almost anything.

After @rynop procedure, here’s what I did:

```
// Rest of @rynop procedure, modulo this configure options
./configure --enable-memcached-igbinary --disable-memcached-sasl
```

Install [jordansissel/fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)

```
apt-get install -y pkg-config ruby-dev gcc
gem install fpm
```

Then, check the package contents you want to replace and let’s replicate for our own purposes.

```
dpkg --list | grep php5-memcached
find /var/cache/apt -type f -name '*php5-memcached*'
dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-memcached_2.1.0-6build1_amd64.deb
```

I figured out in the output that I only needed a few folders, so I created them.

```
mkdir -p etc/php5/mods-available/
// Adjust memcached.ini to suit your tastes, then prepare it for packaging
cp memcached.ini etc/php5/mods-available/
// Make sure the usr/lib/php5/foo path matches in 
// the result of `dpkg -c` you issued
mkdir -p usr/lib/php5/20121212/
cp modules/memcached.so usr/lib/php5/20121212/
```

Magic will happen

```
fpm -s dir -t deb -n php5-memcached -v 2.2.0-wpd -m '<your@email.org>' --description 'PHP 5.5 PECL igbinary + memcached support' -d libmemcached10 etc/ usr/
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7.2 with installed libmemcached-devel version 1.0.16 you should answer the question with **/usr**:

`libmemcached directory [no] : /usr`